# show checkboxes in right after next React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have checkboxes that i need to show right after each element. When I removed the `position: absolute` it shows on top of each other.[image: when position removed].
what I want is to show these in one line(row)

Code

```
            <div className='checkbox-container left2'>
            <input id='a4' name='A4' type='checkbox'  onChange={(e) =>handleChecked(e)} 
            className={'table-seats'}/>
            <label htmlFor='a4' className='btn'>A4</label>
            </div>
            <div className='checkbox-container left2'>
            <input id='a5' name='A5' type='checkbox'  onChange={(e) =>handleChecked(e)} 
            className={'table-seats'}/>
            <label htmlFor='a5' className='btn'>A5</label>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.checkbox-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  }

.table-seats{
  display:flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: url(./img/table_default.png);
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: content-box ;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-width: 0;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.table-seats:checked{
    background: url(./img/table_selected.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
}

.left2{
  position: absolute;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  /* top: 250px;
  right: 235px; */
}
```

[image: need checkbox here]
[image: desired view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display:flex;` from `.table-seats`

#### UPDATE (based on OP comment)

> updated code with your answer but i need both in 1 line

ADD a wrapper and set to `display: flex`

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

.checkbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.table-seats {
  cursor: pointer;
  appearance: none;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/200?id=1');
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-width: 0;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.table-seats:checked {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/200?id=2');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class='checkbox-container left2'>
    <input id='a4' name='A4' type='checkbox' class="table-seats" />
    <label for='a4' class='btn'>A4</label>
  </div>
  <div class='checkbox-container left2'>
    <input id='a5' name='A5' type='checkbox' class="table-seats" />
    <label for='a5' class='btn'>A5</label>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: it worked but now the label(A4,A5) is showing on right. can that be moved inside of the checkbox or bottom of it?

Comment: show me your desired output